# Tkinter Dropdown options menu using Enum

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, enums, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make a window that will hold all the current data for an object, and will let me change it. I'm stuck on how to make the options menu hold values of the enum and to save the selection as the correct enum key.

Here is my current code, which is being called on the button click:

```
current = tk.StringVar()
current .set(self.CustomEnum.value)
tk.OptionMenu(infoMenu, current, [e.value for e in CustomEnum]).pack()
```

This is the result of the list comprehension:

```
['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
```

I'm more focused on getting it to display correctly as right now the only option in the menu is

```
Option1 {Option 2} {Option 3}
```

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from enum import Enum

window = tk.Tk()

class CustomEnum(Enum):
    Option1 = "Option1"
    Option2 = "Option2"

current = tk.StringVar()
current .set(CustomEnum.Option1.value)
tk.OptionMenu(window, current, [e.value for e in CustomEnum]).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to display them correctly add a `*`. i.e. `tk.OptionMenu(window, current, *[e.value for e in CustomEnum]).pack()`

Comment: You're welcome. Here's a little [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already pointed out in a comment, you just needed to add an `*` character to the line that creates the `OptionMenu` widget to unpack the list of values in the list. This is required because each one of them needs to each be passed as separate argument.

Although not strictly necessary, I would also suggest changing the definition of the custom `Enum` to make it a little more succinct, as well as make a few other minor changes to the code.

Here's the result:

```
from enum import Enum
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

CustomEnum = Enum(value='CustomEnum',
                  names='Option1 Option2 Option3')

current = tk.StringVar(value=CustomEnum.Option1.name)
tk.OptionMenu(window, current, *[option.name for option in CustomEnum]).pack()
#tk.OptionMenu(window, current, *list(CustomEnum.__members__)).pack()  # An alternative.

window.mainloop()
```